# Starmap planet path algorithm

Tags: java

I have recently been trying to create an open-space civ style game in Java. I want the star map to be random every time. Players should only be able to travel to different planets along certain paths.

I have been able to randomly generate a set of stars that is suitable for my needs. However, I have been unable to make stars connect to each other in a way that looks user friendly and simple. I am aiming for a look rather like this:
http://philip.bladen.me.uk/java/ExampleStarmap.png
and have only been able to achieve this:
http://philip.bladen.me.uk/java/Starmap.png

My current algorithm takes each star and allows it to have between 1 and 3 neighbors. It picks the nearest stars to it for neighbors. This algorithm is fairly simple yet leads to some stars not being connected to the main star group, therefore not allowing players to get to them.

I am looking for an algorithm that can take a set of points (stars) and generate a list of lines that would make a star system similar to my first image link. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

```
    ArrayList<Star> s = new ArrayList<Star>();
    s.addAll(stars); // Add this chunk's stars

    for (StarChunk c : chunks) // Get the 8 neighboring chunks
    {
        if (c == null)
            continue;

        s.addAll(c.getStars());
    }

    Iterator<Star> i = stars.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        boolean removed = false;
        Star star = i.next();
        for (Star star2 : s)
        {
            if (star != star2 && distance(star, star2) < 30) // Remove stars that are too close
            {
                if (!removed)
                {
                    i.remove();
                    removed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (Star star : stars)
    {
        for (Star star2 : star.getPaths())
        {
            for (Star star3 : s)
            {
                if (star3 == star)
                    continue;
                for (Star star4 : star.getPaths())
                {
                    if (Line2D.linesIntersect(star.getX(), star.getY(), star2.getX(), star2.getY(), star3.getX(), star3.getY(), star4.getX(), star4.getY())) // Remove intersecting paths - doesn't fully work
                    {
                        star4.getPaths().remove(star3);
                        star3.getPaths().remove(star4);
                        System.out.println("Removed");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (final Star star : stars)
    {
        Collections.sort(s, new Comparator<Star>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Star s1, Star s2)
            {
                return distance(s1, star) < distance(s2, star) ? -1 : distance(s1, star) == distance(s2, star) ? 0 : 1;
            }
        });
        for (Star star2 : s)
        {
            if (star2 != star)
            {
                if (star.getPaths().size() < star.capacity && star2.getPaths().size() < star2.capacity)
                {
                    star.addNearby(star2); // Add a path between star and star2
                    star2.addNearby(star);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In order for us to help you improve your algorithm, it's necessary for you to provide your code.

Comment: Hint: start with a complete graph of all stars and find a minimum spanning tree.